# Why I can not run PHP or JSP applications on apache2.2 ?( var/www)

Tags: apache2

I have recently installed apache 2.2 from repos. Im trying to run php and jsp pages using that server.

What Im doing is ,Frist Im creating the pages using Gedit and then copy/pasting them to var/www

When Im trying to access the pages from localhost Im getting raw text. The scripts on those pages does not executing.

When I run "php -version" Im getting this:

```
PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 11 2012 02:17:16) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

I have php,apache so what I need more to do to run PHP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing the CLI version of PHP does not install PHP for Apache. For that, you need to install the `libapache2-mod-php5` package.

Answer (score 1):

you might also need to enable the module with the command

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

and then reload the apache configuration with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

if you ever want to disable the module for apache, the command is

```
sudo a2dismod modulename
```

Comment: * Reloading web server config apache2                                          ulimit: 88: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
httpd not running, trying to start
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: Not working ! What is wrong ?

Comment: It says httpd not running then how im getting this when I use localhost: It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Comment: @CuriousApprentice You need `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

We can run both LAMPP and apache2 on Ubuntu.
When you need to start LAMPP
just stop apache. Here's the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

When you need to start apache2 use this commans:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```